# VB6 webbrowser error can't get outerhtml property

Tags: vb6, browser, outerhtml

I have old program was created it by VB6 and it was working good,
I am using web browser control to load a webpage, then get the html inside a string, recently I received the below error message when I tried to load HTML code to a string variable, it's happen with big pages only.

[image]

My code as below

```
Dim html As String
Private Sub GetHtm_Click()
   WebBrowser1.Navigate (webVar)
   Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Not WebBrowser1.Busy
    html = WebBrowser1.Document.documentElement.outerHTML
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to place your html = outerhtml inside the WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebBrowser1.Document.documentElement.outerHTML` only works in `DocumentComplete` Events.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete()

  html = WebBrowser1.Document.documentElement.outerHTML

End Sub
```

Comment: I have used this method (my code above) for several projects and it was working correctly, but it appeared only when I opened a big html page inside the webbrowser, it may be a memory issue?